# Map Activity crashing on getFragmentById

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Ok, so this USED to work. I just migrated to a clean installation of Windows 8.1 and now when I run this on my Android phone, the app crashes with a Null Pointer Exception pointing to the `((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` line.

Why is this? My understanding of Android is rudimentary at best, the more detailed you can be the better.

MapActivity.java

http://pastebin.com/HvNKd84G

Code fragment:

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

        private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
        protected GoogleMap mMap;
        String locAddr;
        String locName;
        Double locLongitude;
        Double locLatitude;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
               //NullPointer here
               ....
               ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok, so this USED to work.

Not as currently written. :-)

> Why is this?

You are not calling `setContentView()` before calling `findFragmentById()`, and so the fragment does not exist.